# Legacy folder not found while rEFInd booting under OS X

Tags: dual-boot

I've set up a bootable elementary OS USB Stick, and installed rEFInd under OS X 10.10.4.

When I reboot, I see the boot manager, and select my USB Stick afterwards. But then, I'm getting an error message:

> **Error:** Not found while loading legacy folder

I followed [these instructions](http://www.elementarynow.com/dual-booting-elementary-os-and-osx/) on the elementarynow website.

**Did anybody has the same problems in the past? How can I get such a legacy folder?**

Comment: Did elephantery's answer worked for you?

Comment: No, sadly it didn't.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Did you find another solution then?

Comment: No, nothing so far. I stopped a while ago trying though.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://refit.sourceforge.net/doc/c4s1_notfound.html) might resolve your issue:

```
Problem: When choosing a legacy operating system (e.g. Windows) from the rEFIt boot menu, you get an error message saying "Error: Not found while loading legacy loader"

Solution: If you have a Mac Pro and are running rEFIt 0.7 or earlier, this is a known problem that is fixed in rEFIt 0.8. (This may also apply to other recent Core 2 Duo based models.)

If you have another model of Intel Mac: To boot legacy operating systems on the iMac, MacBook Pro (15") or Mac mini, you need to install the firmware updates published together with Boot Camp. Here’s a table of the firmware versions as seen in System Profiler:

(...)
```